# How exactly does Haskell's Network.UDP `accept` work?

Tags: haskell, udp

In [Network.UDP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-udp-0.0.0/docs/Network-UDP.html), `accept :: ListenSock -> ClientSockAddr -> IO UDPSock`

I understand how to call this function and I've read the source code for it. However, when I try to use it, it causes my code to hang at the accept and never advance.

Is the client supposed to do something after the fact to complete the acceptance? Assume we've created a client UDP socket, which is of type `UDPSocket`. Assume we've created a server UDP socket, which is of type `ListenSocket`. If the client, in another thread, sends bytes to the server, then should this complete? Because my code never completes; it just sits there seemingly waiting for an acceptance to complete.

```hs
let (incomingData, clientSockAddr) = recvFrom serverSocket
accept serverSocket clientSockAddr
```

I know that UDP is a connectionlist protocol, so running `accept` to have the server send data to the client is not strictly necessary (because `sendTo :: ListenSocket -> Bytes -> ClientSockAddr -> IO ()` exists), but the `accept` function exists in this module, so I want to understand it.

Comment: This doesn't call any actual `accept` system call (makes no sense for UDP). All it does is create a new socket and call `bind` and `connect` on it. My understanding is that neither of those should hang, ever. Can you check which underlying call hangs?

Comment: `let (incomingData, clientSockAddr) = recvFrom serverSocket` could never coompile. What is the actual code you are running?

Comment: In my testing, your proposed design works fine.  Any chance your server is hanging on the initial `recvfrom` and the client is sending the UDP packet to the wrong host/port, or not sending the packet at all?  Otherwise, a minimum runnable example would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Also, Network.UDP appears to not just implement a traditional UDP API. If you read the documentation you linked to, it talks about a "TCP-like API", outlined at https://kazu-yamamoto.hatenablog.jp/entry/2022/02/25/153122. I couldn't really understand it, but I wouldn't use this package if you're just looking to do plain old UDP.